# xslt creation for xml tag throughing attribute errot

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to create an xslt for my xml tags which consists of links, images and text. I tried but I could not create it. Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my xml and xslt in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N8MnE/2/.

When I run it in [this tool](http://xslttest.appspot.com/) I am getting the following error:

> XSLT Error: The markup in the document preceding the root element must
>   be well-formed.

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:value-of select="ImageBlock / Image " /></xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message tells you, you still have a well-formedness error.  The next one is

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Datum[@Name="ATTservicesTab"]//TabHeading"/>
```

Notice that you're nesting double quotes inside of double quotes.  You can rewrite this as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Datum[@Name='ATTservicesTab']//TabHeading"/>
```

in the four places where it occurs.  Then your stylesheet will parse.

I strongly recommend getting a good tool for working with XML, such as `nxml-mode` for emacs.  You could find an error like this in about 0.2s.

Comment: thanks for your reply...again i corrected the quotes and ran in this tool http://xslttest.appspot.com/ but i am getting this error Error: Failed to compile stylesheet. 2 errors detected. http://jsfiddle.net/jBAz5/

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT is not well-formed XML. You XSLT contains spaces between `<` and next character, i.e.:

```
< xsl
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....i formatted even though i am getting the errorhttp://jsfiddle.net/HLjKL/

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
///Datum
```

that occurred twice, change that to

```
//Datum
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you edit it in the fiddle and send it...could not understand

Comment: go to xsltransform.net and copy-paste your xsl there, you will see the line that causes the error (the locations where `///Datum` appeared)

Comment: i am facing one more error can you help me in fixing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631856/not-retrieving-html-value-through-xslt